# nasm rejects fst tword [mem] --- bug?

Tags: nasm, x87

`fst tword [mem]` generates a compilation error under nasm (generates "error: invalid combination of opcode and operands").

`fst qword [mem]` is accepted by nasm.

`fstp tword [mem]` and `fstp qword [mem]` are both accepted by nasm.

Is this a bug in nasm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Intel's manual:

```
FST/FSTP—Store Floating Point Value

Opcode   Instruction  64-Bit   Compat/Leg  Description
                      Mode     Mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
D9 /2    FST m32fp   Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to m32fp.
DD /2    FST m64fp   Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to m64fp.
DD D0+i  FST ST(i)   Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to ST(i).
D9 /3    FSTP m32fp  Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to m32fp and pop register stack.
DD /3    FSTP m64fp  Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to m64fp and pop register stack.
DB /7    FSTP m80fp  Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to m80fp and pop register stack.
DD D8+i  FSTP ST(i)  Valid     Valid       Copy ST(0) to ST(i) and pop register stack.
```

As you can see, there's no `m80fp` (i.e. `tword`) variant of `FST`, but there is for `FSTP`.